# NodeJS Complex Mysql Query with Aliases?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, select

Here's a simple MySQL query I'm using in NodeJS which works just fine;

```
Audiopost.getAll = result => {
  sql.query("SELECT * FROM audioposts", (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(null, err);
      return;
    }

    console.log("audioposts: ", res);
    result(null, res);
  });
};
```

However, when I try to replace the "SELECT * FROM audioposts" statement with a more complex query, I get;

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.
```

Here's the more complex query which comes from a PHP page;

```
SELECT
    ap.audioname, 
    ap.userid, 
    ap.audioid, 
    ap.title, 
    ap.likes,
    ap.opid,
    u.gavatar, 
    u.name, 
    u.email,
    u.bio,
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.tagname)
        FROM entitytag et
        LEFT JOIN tags t on t.tagid = et.tagid
        WHERE et.audioid = ap.audioid
    ) tagname,
    (
      SELECT count(*) FROM audioposts op WHERE op.opid = ap.audioid
    ) as replycount
        FROM audioposts ap 
        LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = ap.userid
      WHERE ap.opid = '0'
```

Am I allowed to use aliases in SQL code for nodeJS? What am I doing wrong? How can I execute this query?

Comment: Yes, you can run any valid query also on in node. And please show your actual code and not describe what you are replacing. The error you are seeing is not SQL but JS, so you are probably missing something during replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newlines aren't allowed in single- and double-quoted strings in javascript. You'll need to either replace all the line breaks with `\n` or use backticks instead of quotes to define your string. Backticks (`) create a template literal, which allows newlines.

```js
let query = `
SELECT
    ap.audioname, 
    ap.userid, 
    ap.audioid, 
    ap.title, 
    ap.likes,
    ap.opid,
    u.gavatar, 
    u.name, 
    u.email,
    u.bio,
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.tagname)
        FROM entitytag et
        LEFT JOIN tags t on t.tagid = et.tagid
        WHERE et.audioid = ap.audioid
    ) tagname,
    (
      SELECT count(*) FROM audioposts op WHERE op.opid = ap.audioid
    ) as replycount
        FROM audioposts ap 
        LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = ap.userid
      WHERE ap.opid = '0'
`;

sql.query(query, (err, res) => {/* ... */})
```